# How to customize a title by passing query string?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, query, title, wp-title

I have a profile page, it is a template. Every time when I click one of a doctor, the profile page will show the specific doctor info by passing a query string. Something like
profile?doctorName=abc.
I have rewrote to profile/abc.

Now the page title is "profile | blog name", But I would like to change the title to
"abc(doctor's name) | hospital name".(Different doctor is in different hospital). This is my code below, and I tried to put it in the function.php and the profile template:

```
   <title><?php if (is_page( physician_single_pg()))
           {
            echo something               ////How to get the doctor name
            echo " | ".(our_doctors()); //the hospital name, get from the plugin                
           }
          else
            {
            wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
            }
          ?>
    </title>
```

I am thinking maybe I can push the query string to the plugin and pull it out in the header. But I don't know how to do that.

I didn't get any luck. Please help, every suggestion is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, just use get query var to get the doctor name.

Comment: Care to post your solution as a proper answer?

Comment: This is not the best answer, I am still wondering how to make this edition in the plugin:). Right now, it is in the header.php, which means uses cannot change the title. But yes, at least this is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [wp_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter. just remove all your code from header.php and put this into your plugin instead:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_wp_title', 10, 2 );

function my_wp_title( $title, $sep = '|' ) {

    if ( is_page( physician_single_pg() ) and get_query_var( 'doctor' ) ) {
        $doctor = get_query_var( 'doctor' );
        $title = ... // here you put your code to build your title from the doctor & hospital name
    }

    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );

function my_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'doctor';

    return $vars;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, I tried this code. It works. I have a question: it cannot display the query string properly. For the doctor name, I have to pull a query string from the current page. Is there any way I can get that value from the plugin?

Comment: The description is at the top of the first post.

Comment: i've added a function to add your query variable and added the code to check/retrieve its value. let me know if that works.

Comment: It works! Okay, now I know how to pull a data from other page to plugin. Thank you!